# NPM issue using React

Tags: npm

I currently have an issue where I can no longer work, with a machine that I bought using NPM. The issue does not run using **npm start**.

> david@Davids-MacBook-Pro happy % npm start
> **npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE**
> **npm ERR! errno 1**
> **npm ERR! happy@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`**
> **npm ERR! Exit status 1**
> **npm ERR!**
> **npm ERR! Failed at the happy@0.1.0 start script.**
> **npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.**

**npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:**
**npm ERR!     /Users/david/.npm/_logs/2020-08-09T06_56_49_544Z-debug.log**

This is the main issue. Also have "2020-08-09T06_56_49_544Z-debug.log"

Can anyone help me...

Thanks you,
David

[The NPM One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOZa.png)

[2020-08-09T06_56_49_544Z-debug.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8rOw.png)

Comment: Have you tried the steps recommended in the long error message you posted a picture of?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this from your `/Users/david/` directory.  You need to navigate to the root of your project (where `package.json` is), then do `npm start`:

```
$ cd path/to/my/project
$ npm start
```

**Update:**

Add that `babel-eslint` package to your `package.json`.

Show your directory tree inside `users/David/happy`

Comment: There are a few different site that all have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I need more info to work with this.  What type to package on the david or david/happy ?

This is on Mac which I bought two month ago, and have had this NPM issue from the beginning.

Comment: Show your directory tree inside `users/David/happy`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much. I have finally been able to make NPM work using because there are two different type of sites ~/david and ~/david/happy.

I completely removed the NPM of ~/david, and now only have NPM for ~/david/happy working now.

**the issue is
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8781**